# error 'Arguments to path.join must be strings' when adding custom Plugin Phonegap 3.0

Tags: plugins, cordova, npm

this is a port of an older twitter plugin that I am just trying to get to work with PG > 3.0, I have this working fine on my IDE, so I wanted to share with others, for some reason when I try and do the install via NPM it errors. I have re-read the file system structure and plugin.xml specification, and cannot see any errors.

I even changed the ID of the plugin from CDVPluginTwitter incase the prefix was throwing an error, however I still get

```
path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/plugins.js:72:39
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1707:7
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

The Git is located here, https://github.com/ednasgoldfishuk/CDVPluginTwitter/tree/master

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was missing the finishing `</plugin>` tag in plugin.xml, Github has been updated and now is confirmed installable on PhoneGap 3.0 +

Comment: Thank you so much, I was missing the slash on the closing plugin tag and was going insane looking for what was wrong.